# onTapgesture disabling buttons of View SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I have a view with two buttons, and I added `.onTapGesture` to toggle the view.
But after I add `.onTapGesture`, buttons are underneath it and not responding.
Is there any way to use both together

```
MenuView()

.onTapGesture{
self.isShowing.toggle()
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a simultaneous gesture:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
  
  var body: some View {
    
    let tapGesture = TapGesture()
      .onEnded { _ in
        print("Menu tapped")
      }
    
    menuView
      .simultaneousGesture(tapGesture)
  }
  
  var menuView: some View {
    VStack {
      Button {
        print("Item 1 hit")
      } label: {
        Text("Item 1")
      }
      
      Button {
        print("Item 2 hit")
      } label: {
        Text("Item 2")
      }
    }
  }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  
  static var previews: some View {
    Group {
      TestView()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: any ideas how to ignore tap gesture if button was tapped? like UIKit's `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`